# I can't do a migration in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

This is my first ever question. I don't remember the version of the .NET that I'm using and I don't know how to find out so if you need it please tell me how to find out.

I'm using visual studio 2022

Every time I try to do a migration this pops up

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I don't know what is wrong with this and I can't find an answer.

I'm from argentina so that's why you'll see somethings in Spanish.

This is a group project so I'll thank if anyone can help me soon.

When I type `add-migration -Name inicial` it fails and the message provided pops up.

This is my context:

```
using cinepolis.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace cinepolis.DataBase
{
    public class CinepolisContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        //constructor donde establecemos opciones
        public CinepolisContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        //Entidades que va a manejar
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Empleado> Empleados { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Reserva> Reservas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sala> Salas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Funcion> Funciones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pelicula> Peliculas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my settings (it's the `appsettings.json` file)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CinepolisDBCS": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=CinepolisDB;Trusted_Connection=true;"
  }
}
```

This is my startup file:

```
using cinepolis.DataBase;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace cinepolis
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static WebApplication InicializarApp(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            ConfigureServices(builder);

            var app = builder.Build();
            Configure(app);

            return app;
        }

        private static void ConfigureServices(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CinepolisContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CinepolisDBCS")));
            
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        }

        public static void Configure(WebApplication app)
        {
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Version check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions

Comment: Unrelated: I know, it is tempting to write code in your native language. But that makes it harder to understand as soon as you need to present it to an international audience like here. I always suggest practicing to code in English, knowing the troubles of non- English native speakers first hand.

Comment: Accoring to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) you need to have the following public constructor
```public CinepolisContext (DbContextOptions<CinepolisContext > options) : base(options)```.

Comment: You can double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File,  in the  `<TargetFramework>` you will see the version of the .NET.

Comment: What's your webApplication ? We use IServiceCollection to inject service . You can read [The Startup class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-startup-class) to know more .